# Internationalization with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm currently very new with rails and quite confused. I am doing a school project that requires making a website, and my part is doing the internationalization part. So far i have made a drop down menu that would change the language whenever the language is selected, but i am unable to translate. I am not sure if i am supposed to include another file to specify what  languages i want to be able to support, because after checking many websites, it just left me with much more confusion.

Thanks!

Comment: Good explanation is here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the rails guide on i18n? There is fine described how to do it.
Generally in your config/lang are the file for the different languages.

Textelements are place with <%= t :first_text_block, :default => "Hello I'm a multilangual text", %>

[Guide rails for internationalisation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)